# Dev server error reading auth token from response data

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm facing this error while I do npm start on react project, I'm not able to figure out the reason please provide any pointers to proceed further

```
src\main\web\server\auth.js:125
  return res.end(`Dev server error reading auth token from response data: ${er.message}`)

TypeError: res.end is not a function

  at IncomingMessage.res.on (C:\backup\ui-app\src\main\web\server\auth.js:125:22)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1081:12)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Comment: Please provide the code for your server side where `res.end` is being called so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is pretty straight-forward in a sense. What is it telling you is that in your file `auth.js` on line `25` you wanted to use `.end` method on `res` variable, but this `res` variable does not have this method.
Why can that be? Most likely it's value is of a different type than you've assumed, ie. this is not a `response`.
This may occur due to the names shadowing or asynchronous code execution or simple coding error, but without more code it's impossible to tell. If you post `auth.js` I will most likely be able to help you a bit more.